# Under What assumptions on $p$, $\mathcal{O}_K^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p^{*} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

Let $p$ be a fixed prime number and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the field of $p$-adic numbers and $K$ be an extension of degree $2$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$ and $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ be the group of units of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Under what conditions on $p$, we can prove that $\mathcal{O}_K^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p^{*} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$

Comment: The structure of the principal units (those congruent to 1 modulo the maximal ideal) is discussed in another MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36575/generators-of-the-principal-unit-group-in-local-fields-of-characteristic-0. See answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\ge3$ be a prime number and $K$ any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. The torsion part of $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ is always cyclic. On the other side, the torsion part of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ is isomorphic to $$\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$$ which is not cyclic. See Henri Cohen's Number Theory, volume 1, section 4.3. There, he gives an explicit descritption of the group of units of $\mathcal{O}_K$. If I remeber correctly, this also appears in Iwasawa's book on Local Class Field Theory.

Edit: I forgot the condition $p\ge3$, thanks Keith.

Comment: That group is cyclic if $p = 2\ldots$

Comment: @KConrad Yes, in the comment that I wrote and deleted, I wrote that condition, and I forgot to put it here. Now it remains the case $p=2$. I'm busy now. I'll check in a little, or please answer the question and I delete this answer.

Comment: Actually, even the case $p=2$ is problematic.  The torsion part of $\mathbf Z_2^\times$ is $\{\pm 1\} \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ so the torsion subgroup of $\mathbf Z_2^\times \oplus \mathbf Z_2^\times$ is the noncyclic group $\{\pm 1\}^2$ and thus can't be isomorphic to $\mathcal O_K^\times$ in the 2-adic case.

Comment: If we assume that $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ is torsion free then is it possible $\mathcal{O}_K^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_p^*\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Because I want to know under what assumptions $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^*\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^*$

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ is never torsion free, it contains $-1$.

Comment: @ EFinat you mean to say that $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ can never be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^*\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^*$

Comment: Well that's what math tells...

Comment: If we take the torsion free part of $\mathcal{O}_K^*$, which will be $1+\pi\mathcal{O}_K$ where $\pi$ is the uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_K$ then under some assumptions on $p$, Is it possible to prove an isomorphism between the $1+\pi\mathcal{O}_K$ and $(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)\oplus(1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: Please see Corollary 4.3.14 in Cohen's book, and the link that @KConrad posted below your question. The free part of the unit group of the ring of integers of $K$ is always isomorphic to the product of $n$ copies of the $p$-adic integers, where $n$ is the degree of the extension.